# count of option tags inside datalist in android 2.3

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

Why is android 2.3 webkit browser(not chrome) not able to find option inside datalist

HTML

```
<input list="browsers" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

JS

```
 $('datalist > option').length;
 $('datalist').length;
```

In all browsers(desktop chrome, mobile chrome, android 4.1, android 4.4) the answer of js is **5 and 1** But in android 2.3 it's **0 and 1**. Why is android 2.3 not able to find options.

I know android 2.3 doesnt support datalist but it is able to recognize datalist and not it's childrens. Even the below code gives 0

`$('datalist > option').length;`

I am trying to polyfill datalsit using jQueryUI for a hybrid app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have settled with using following html structure which works

```
 datalist --- select -- option
```

By wrapping options in select i get the correct ans.